# How are parachutes usable in other places than Earth?

Tags: mars, moonlanding

Mars landings, Moon landings. . . Wherever I see a documentary or still pictures in Wikipedia, there are parachutes in the landing of rovers. Whenever I see them, I ask myself, "How they can it decelerate the speed of rovers, when there is no / thin air?" Something needs to be there to create friction!

Comment: I am curious to see a reference where parachutes are used to land on the Moon...

Comment: now i come to think of it, i haven't ! General assumption !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parachutes have never been used on the moon, but [they are viable for Mars](http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/spacecraft_edl_parachute.html) because [Mars *does have an atmosphere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mars) - albiet one much lighter than that of Earth.  For that reason, parachutes cannot be the only means of slowing down on Mars --- for example, in the case of the [Curiosity Rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory), that's why an elaborate booster and crane combination was used (see figure).  Another approach, taken by the [Pathfinder Rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Pathfinder), was to use large airbags to bounce on landing.

One benefit to using parachutes on Mars, is that they can be used at higher velocities --- unlike on Earth where the heavier atmosphere (and thus stronger drag force) would shred a parachute at comparable speeds.

[image]

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens_(spacecraft)#Parachute